# Flutter App stucks at splash Screen what causes that?

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter android release build is stuck on splash screen.

I have tried by cleaning project flutter clean. But still it got stuck on splash screen. I have also used WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); before executing the runApp(). Still it stuck on splash screen. Also haven't found error logs that can be resolved.

It is not happening with debug version or when I run with flutter run --release. The app is running smoothly in flutter run --release.

I'm using flutter 1.22.0 & VSCode 1.49.3. Testing & releasing for android.

I'm stuck with this last 3 days. It would be very helpful if anyone can help me.

Comment: Are you using any library/package on Splash i.e SharedPreferences. Run Release Build on your device, connect it with your system. Open Android Studio and see logs there, may be there you'll find issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.